# Issue in Painting submenu

Tags: html, css

In following code on hover of menu1 I want to show submenu but it will not work.I applied below `css`. Please modified the code where I am wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="primary_nav_wrap">
        <ul>
            <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <div class="sub_divsavedfun" id="Functions_1-5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
        .primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul ul 
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
    </style>
```

If I remove `<div class="sub_divsavedfun" id="Functions_1-5">` then it will work.But as per requirement I have add `div` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in css and it's working fine

You add div before the sub  `ul` so, in css `.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul` not found any `ul`. because structure of HTML element is now  `.primary_nav_wrap ul > li > div > ul`

```
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > div > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mrob21h7/3/)

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover .sub_divsavedfun > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrob21h7/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have `div` direct child of `li` not `ul`. So just **replace** following code:

```
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
```

**to :**

```
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover div > ul, .primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul  {
  display: block
}
```

**Working Snippet :**

```css
.primary_nav_wrap {
  margin-top: 15px
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item {
  background: #ddd
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px
}
.primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}
/* CODE REPLACED BY BELOW
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
*/

/*Code added */
.primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover div > ul, .primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul  {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="primary_nav_wrap">
  <ul>
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <div class="sub_divsavedfun" id="Functions_1-5">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```